# jQuery animation won't fade in

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

EDIT:

Here's my full code from `<html>` to `</html>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <style>
    .product-row
    {
        opacity: 0;
        background-image: url('../img/airplane-background.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 50px 0px 100px 0px;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>

    <script>
        $('div.product-row').animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: 3000 });
    </script>

    </head> 

    <body>
        <div class="product-row">
            <section>
                <div> 
                    <h1>Products</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>                
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it's just not working even though the jsfiddle code posted by a responder is working?

---

I'm trying to get an entire div, which happens to contain a background image defined in CSS, to fade in by using the animate effect in jQuery. But all this code seems to do is make the entire div transparent without increasing the opacity via the animate effect.

What am I missing here?

```
<style>
.product-row
{
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url('../img/airplane-background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 50px 0px 100px 0px;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<script>
    $('div.product-row').animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: 3000 });
</script>

<div class="product-row">
    <section>
        <div> 
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>                
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: [It appears to work](https://jsfiddle.net/3rhkortu/) for me. Is that not the result you desire?

Comment: @Stryner I can see how your jsfiddle link shows that it's working. I'm baffled as to why my very stripped-down, basic version of your code isn't also working when I run it. I'm editing the question to show the full code, from `<html>` to `</html>`. Can you see what I might have missed? I can't, and I copied the elements directly from your code.

Comment: The only thing I see missing in your code, which is enabled in fiddles by default, is that your code is not running in a ready handler. Try wrapping your script in `$(document).ready(function() { /* CODE HERE */ }`

Comment: Ok, that's what the problem was. I think I was misunderstanding the last "Tip" section in the [W3Schools jQuery syntax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp) that seems to say you can leave that out.

Comment: The tip at the bottom of the page says you can also use the (equivalent) syntax `$(function(){ /* CODE HERE */ })`, but it does not say to exclude it. If you want to exclude it, then the `<script>` tag has to appear below the tags you are manipulating in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.fadeIn()` effect instead.

[How to Fade in element](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: Tried that as well. Still nothing. I've edited the question to include the full `<html>` to `</html>` code. Any idea why it all works in jsfiddle but not on an actual web server? My browser Inspector is showing zero errors.